# How to subscribe to GPS data published by MTI-G-700 xsens_driver?

Tags: ros, driver, xsens, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm trying to make a state publisher for our custom robot, I managed to receive GPS data published on "/mti/sensor/gnssPvt". So it sends data. In my state_publisher.cpp I have:

```
#include "sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h"
```

and

```
ros::Subscriber gnss_sub = g.subscribe("/mti/sensor/gnssPvt", 1000, gnssCallback);
```

and fro callBack I have:

```
void gnssCallback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix::ConstPtr& msg) {
```

I get following warning by running xsens_driver:

```
[WARN] [1542263240.955337]: Could not process inbound connection: topic types do not match: [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix] vs. [custom_msgs/gnssSample]{'topic': '/mti/sensor/gnssPvt', 'tcp_nodelay': '0', 'md5sum': '2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48', 'type': 'sensor_msgs/NavSatFix', 'callerid': '/state_publisher'}
```

And I don't receive data in my state_publisher.cpp node.
F.Y.I I did same implementation for IMU data subscribing to "imu_raw" and it works:

```
#include "sensor_msgs/Imu.h"
```

and

```
ros::Subscriber imu_sub = m.subscribe("imu_raw", 1000, imuCallback);
```

for callBack:

```
void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg) {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308550/how-to-subscribe-to-gps-data-published-by-mti-g-700-xsens_driver?/) by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer, here it is:

```
#include <custom_msgs/gnssSample.h>
```

and for callBack:

```
 void gnssCallback(const custom_msgs::gnssSample::ConstPtr& msg) {
```

also don't forget to add "custom_msgs" to CMakeLists.txt of your package:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
.
.
custom_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) with karma: 18 on 2018-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0